# AngularJs - QueryString value & ng-include

Tags: angularjs

**I am trying to capture the querystring and apply the value to my ng-include.**

My querystring: http://mydomain.com/?target=W7ROP175T5TEHW2

My MainCtrl: $scope.target = $location.search()['target'];

$scope.target is picking up the value.

Doing a simple text write, ie {{target}} works.

**This does not work:  `<div ng-include="'/_UserSession/{{target}}/assets/menu.html'"></div>`**

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm...I don't think the {{}} are necessary since you're already writing in Angular

Comment: so what would be the syntax? Cannot be < div ng-include="'/_UserSession/target/assets/menu.html'">

Comment: Nope, I'm looking right now, can't seem to find anything relevant tho. If you just do `ng-include="target"` is `target` being defined or just plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OK, I solved it, I hope this helps others as well:**

#### HTML

```
<ng-include src="session()"></ng-include>
```

#### Controller

```
$scope.target = $location.search()['target'];

$scope.session = function() {
    return "/_UserSession/" + $scope.target + "/assets/menu.html";
};
```

Comment: what error did you see in your original post? btw, you can't put a space between `<` and `div`, make sure it looks like `<div ` in your code.

Comment: I only put the space there because Stackoverflow wouldn't show the line as code

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the value, it is an expression.

```
ng-include="'/_UserSession/' + target + '/assets/menu.html'"
```

Also if you want to make sure that target is set before it attempts to include the template, you can add `ng-if ="target"`. This way it will avoid a bad request.

Comment: Is there a need to call `encodeURIComponent` on `target`? I mean in general. Is there a need to URL-esacape concatenated variables or is Angular clever enough to figure out that this is a URL?